# Android - view a file cause Exception on one device

Tags: android

Trying to open an Excel file, previously saved from android app
with the using of implicit Intent.
On some devices it works fine, but on one device (Huawei P6) the app crashes
all the time I perform this action or when i try to open containing folder in a file manager with using of Intent. I am getting FileNotFoundException.

- The file is actually exists (I can see it in a file manager).
- I can open and view the file with the build in app (If I run it from
  the    file manager).

But I can not open this file from my app neither to view neither to browse in a file manager (again this works fine on other devices).

Code:

```
/* 
 * Opening a file.
 *
 * @param file
 *            - File to be opened
 */

private void openSavedFile(File file) {

    PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

    // checking whether device can handle current intent
    if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null && file.isFile()) {
        // Got Activity to handle intent

        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.setData(uri);
        this.startActivity(intent);

    } else {
        Log.d(TAG, "No Intent available to open excel file");
        showMessageInACustomToast(getResources().getString(
                R.string.no_excel_app));
    }
}

/**
 * Open a file browser and shows the folder which contains the file passed
 * as a parameter.
 * 
 * @param file
 *            - File to be shown in file browser
 */
public void openFolder(File file) {

    if (file.exists()) {
        file = file.getParentFile();

        Uri selectedUri = Uri.fromFile(file);

        PackageManager packageManager = this.getPackageManager();

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);

        // checking whether device can handle current intent
        if (intent.resolveActivity(packageManager) != null) {
            // Got Activity to handle intent

            intent.setDataAndType(selectedUri, "resource/folder");
            startActivity(intent);

        } else {
            Log.d(TAG,
                    "No Intent available to open folder in a file manager");
            showMessageInACustomToast(getResources().getString(
                    R.string.no_file_manager_app));
        }
    }
}
```

The app crashes after calling of startActivity() in both cases
and caches RemoteException in execStartActivity method of Instrumentation class.

Here is what I can see in the log (again it is similar for viewing the file or opening in a file manager:

UPDATE: as found on the internet huawei has a bug and
logcat shows a suspicious FileNotFoundException, which is not a real cause. 
The real cause of crash is hidden and not shown in logcat instead.

```
12-09 11:49:08.235: W/dalvikvm(29245): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40cbb930)
12-09 11:49:10.701: I/Process(29245): Sending signal. PID: 29245 SIG: 9
12-09 11:49:10.821: W/System.err(29476): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/cust/xml/hw_launcher_load_icon.xml: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-09 11:49:10.825: W/System.err(29476):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:409)
12-09 11:49:10.825: W/System.err(29476):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:109)
12-09 11:49:10.825: W/System.err(29476):    at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.readDefaultConfig(ResourcesEx.java:808)
12-09 11:49:10.825: W/System.err(29476):    at android.content.res.ResourcesEx.<init>(ResourcesEx.java:741)
12-09 11:49:10.825: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1721)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.getTopLevelResources(ActivityThread.java:1752)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.LoadedApk.getResources(LoadedApk.java:485)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:1911)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.ContextImpl.init(ContextImpl.java:1904)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleBindApplication(ActivityThread.java:4269)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1300(ActivityThread.java:145)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1306)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
12-09 11:49:10.828: W/System.err(29476):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
12-09 11:49:10.831: W/System.err(29476):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5095)
12-09 11:49:10.831: W/System.err(29476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
12-09 11:49:10.831: W/System.err(29476):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
12-09 11:49:10.831: W/System.err(29476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:898)
12-09 11:49:10.831: W/System.err(29476):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:665)
12-09 11:49:10.831: W/System.err(29476):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
12-09 11:49:10.835: W/System.err(29476): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
12-09 11:49:10.835: W/System.err(29476):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
12-09 11:49:10.838: W/System.err(29476):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
12-09 11:49:10.838: W/System.err(29476):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
12-09 11:49:10.838: W/System.err(29476):    ... 19 more
12-09 11:49:10.971: W/System.err(29476): Invalid int: ""
```

What is wrong and how can I handle it?

updated:

Saving file in here:

```
    /**
     * Creates new file
     * 
     * @return new file in Entrepreneur folder
     */

    private File getNewFileName() {

        final String fileName = REPORT_FILE_PREFIX + "TMP.xls";

            // Creating file in external storage
            File sdCard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
            File directory = new File(sdCard.getAbsolutePath()
                    + "/Entrepreneur");

            // create directory if not exist
            if (!directory.isDirectory()) {
                directory.mkdirs();
            }

            // file path
            File file = new File(directory, fileName);

        return file;
    }
```

This device doesn't have a sd card and saves the file into:

```
/storage/emulated/0/Entrepreneur/Entrepreneur_report_TMP.xls
```

(the file exists in this location)

Comment: You are getting `java.io.FileNotFoundException:`. Check whether your file is present at that location.

Comment: Check for `file.canRead()`, I suspect that could be an issue.

Comment: The file exists. file.canRead() = true. Look at updated question please, I added file details.

Comment: Have you given all the required permission in android manifest?

Comment: I have <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>

Comment: You can avoid the crash using try catch.

Comment: Yes thank you. This is the only solution I can see. I wrapped startActivity into try block an catch Exception e. But interestingly somehow it still crashes in the same place. Seemes to be the problem with this exect device.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97476/discussion-between-exception-and-leo).

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's the SDK your phone is running, I can't see any other reason why it would work on other devices but not yours, you may have to change your lowest SDK and target SDK in manifest.xml
Not sure though, only an idea as I had the same problem once before. 
And also google search the error you're getting in the console and you may find what is wrong with it. 
Also what debugging methods have you used?